# Can anyone offer a step-by-step reference about the development of excel plug-in

Tags: c#, excel, plugins, vsto, ribbon

I just start studying how to develop the excel 2010 plug-in by VSTO, and I use C#. But I find it hard to continue. I want to develop the plug-in with interface like there are buttons or checkBox, instead of UDF.( May use Ribbon I believe) I've learnt some from Excel-DNA， but it's not what I want. Can anyone give me a reference or a link on that? Better a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: The VSTO examples include adding a 'custom pane' that sound like they'll meet your needs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Follow the hub: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128771

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provides a decent tutorial here along with samples and object model diagrams.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx

For UI customizations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf08984t.aspx